# iOS app to add slow motion to videos easily

Tags: video-editing, iphone-app

I'd like to be able to easily add multiple sections of slow motion in an MPG video. I've not been able to find a stable app to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use iMovie by Apple for free. Select ranges to add to your timeline, then adjust the speed of the clips by tapping the speed <sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub> button. The clips are appended together and you can add transitions between if you wish.